# Finding a tetrahedron with known sides of the base and the angles opposite to these sides of the side faces.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, solid-geometry, triangulation

Given a tetrahedron ABCD with known sides $a, b, c - AB, AC, BC$ of the base and the angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma - \angle{ADB}, \angle{ADC}, \angle{BDC}$ of the side faces opposite to these sides. Find angle $\phi$ (side edge or height)

[This tetragedron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeVe8.png)

I have some ideas on how to solve this with python scipy, but it іs too complicated and has some edge case problems.

$BD = \frac{a\sin\alpha}{\sin\phi}$, $AD = \frac{a\sin(\alpha+\phi)}{\sin\alpha},$
$$\angle{ACD}=\arcsin\left(\frac{a\sin(\alpha+\phi)\sin\beta}{b\sin\alpha}\right),$$
$CD=\frac{b\sin(\beta+\angle{ACD})}{\sin\beta}=\frac{b\sin\left(\beta+\arcsin\left(\frac{a\sin(\alpha+\phi)\sin\beta}{b\sin\alpha}\right)\right)}{\sin\beta},$
$$\frac{CD^2+BD^2-c^2}{2*BD*CD}-\cos\gamma=0,$$
$$\frac{\left(\frac{b\sin\left(\beta+\arcsin\left(\frac{a\sin(\alpha+\phi)\sin\beta}{b\sin\alpha}\right)\right)}{\sin\beta}\right)^2+\left(\frac{a\sin\alpha}{\sin\phi}\right)^2-c^2}{2\left(\frac{a\sin\alpha}{\sin\phi}\right)\left(\frac{b\sin\left(\beta+\arcsin\left(\frac{a\sin(\alpha+\phi)\sin\beta}{b\sin\alpha}\right)\right)}{\sin\beta}\right)}-\cos\gamma=0,$$
And then I solve this equasion in terms of $\phi$ using python scipy.

So... Are there any other ways? any ideas are welcome.